# Java 8 updating a map in parallel stream

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, concurrenthashmap

I have two loops. In the inner loop, I hit a Database, get the result and perform some computatiosn on the result (which involves calling other private method) and put the result it in a map. 
Will this approach cause any problem like putting `null` for any of the keys?

No two threads will update the same value. i.e)the `key` that is computed will be unique. (If it loops `n` times, there will be `n` keys)

```
Map<String,String> m = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
      obj1.getProp().parallelStream().forEach(k1 -> { //obj.getProp() returns a list
          obj2.parallelStream().forEach(k2-> { //obj2 is a list

              String key = constructKey(k1,k2);
             //Hit a DB and get the result
             //Computations on the result
             //Call some other methods
              m.put(key, result);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the Stream API unless you’ve fully understood that it is more than an alternative spelling for loops. Generally, if your code contains a `forEach` on a stream, you should ask yourself at least once whether this is really the best solution for your task, but if your code contains a *nested* `forEach` calls, you should *know* that it can’t be the right thing.

It might work, as when adding to a concurrent map, like in your question, however, it defeats the purpose of the Stream API.

Besides that, arrays don’t have a `parallelStream()` method, thus, when the result type of `obj.getProp()` and the type of `obj2` are arrays, as your comments say, you have to use `Arrays.stream(…)` to construct a stream.

What you want to do can be implemented as

```
Map<String,String> m = 
    Arrays.stream(obj1.getProp()).parallel()
        .flatMap(k1 -> Arrays.stream(obj2).map(k2 -> constructKey(k1, k2)))
        .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(key -> key, key -> {
            //Hit a DB and get the result
            //Computations on the result
            //Call some other methods
            return result;
        }));
```

The benefit of this is not only a better utilization of parallel processing, but also that it works even if you use `Collectors.toMap`, creating a non-concurrent `Map`, instead of `Collectors.toConcurrentMap`; the framework will take care of producing it in a thread-safe manner.

So unless you definitely need a concurrent map for concurrent later-one processing, you can use either; which one will perform better depends on factors whose discussion would exceed the scope of this answer.

So with the correct usage of the Stream API, it will be thread safe, regardless of which `Map` type you produce, and the remaining question is whether the database access is thread safe, which, [as already explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36326102/2711488) depends on a lot of factors which you didn’t include in your question, so we can’t answer that.

Comment: My apologies. It is not an array it is a list

Comment: From your answer, I can convert Arrays.stream with list.parallelStream

Comment: Yes, it doesn’t matter whether you use `Arrays.stream(array).parallel()` or `list.parallelStream()`, the logic of the stream operation is the same. The entire stream operation will run in parallel mode, therefore, it doesn’t matter whether you use `list.stream()` or `list.parallelStream()` for the inner stream.

Comment: I don't get your last point. How do you say that using `stream()` and `parallelStream()` for the inner stream doesn't make any difference?

Comment: This is a single stream operation despite the function passed to `flatMap` returning new stream instances. Hence, the terms “inner stream” and “outer stream” are only colloquial. The “outer stream”’s `flatMap` implementation determines how the elements of the “inner stream” are processed, so whether the “inner stream” is marked as parallel or sequential is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Your question boils down to the parts "can I add to a concurrent hash map from multiple threads?" and "can I access my database in parallel?"

The answer to the first is: "yes", the answer to the second is "it depends"

Or a little longer: the two parallel streams which you use basically just start the inner lambda on multiple threads in the execution pool. The adding to the map itself is not a problem, that is what the concurrent hash map was made for.

Regarding the database, it depends on how you query it and on which level you share the object. If you use a connection pool with a different connection for each thread, you will probably be fine. For most databases, sharing a connection and getting a new statement per thread is also fine. Sharing a statement and getting a new result set leads to problems for quite a number of database drivers.